# python append weird behavior

Tags: python, list

I have created an object type.. and after initilializing I am pushing that into a list.
but for some reason the behavior is not as expected.
let me put in the sample code.. and then the output.

```
def allignDatesToWhenWasItemSold(pilotInstance):
    unitsSoldPerDay = pilotInstance._units_sold_per_day
    productPart = pilotInstance._product
    date = productPart._date
    quantity = pilotInstance._product._quantity

    listOfPilotInstance = []
    for i in range(len(unitsSoldPerDay)):
        perDayQuantity = unitsSoldPerDay[i]
        #modDate = date
        #print perDayQuantity
        modDate = modifyDate(date, i)
        productPart._date = modDate

        #print "pro ", productPart._date
        newPilotInstance = PilotTest(productPart, pilotInstance._name,perDayQuantity)
        print "here ",newPilotInstance._product._date._date, ' ',newPilotInstance._product._date._month, ' ', newPilotInstance._units_sold_per_day
        #newPilotInstance.setDate(modDate)

        listOfPilotInstance.append(newPilotInstance) #note this line.. this is where the trouble is
        for k in listOfPilotInstance:
            print k._product._date._date

    for ele in listOfPilotInstance:
        print "there " ,ele._product._date._date, ' ',ele._product._date._month, ' ',ele._units_sold_per_day
    return listOfPilotInstance
```

The out put are as following

```
here  30   7   1
30
here  31   7   0
31<--- now this shouldnt be like this.. as I am doing append.. teh first ele shoulnt be overwrited??
31
here  1   8   2
1
1
1
there  1   8   1
there  1   8   0
there  1   8   2
```

So my query is that since I am doing the append.. why is the date element getting overwrited?
Any clue as in what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: A note: `for i, perDayQuantity in enumerate(unitsSoldPerDay):` is more pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same productpart instance, and just mutating it:

```
productPart._date = modDate
```

Since all the `PilotTest` objects have a reference to the same `productPart` instance, *all* of them see the mutation.

You need to create a new instance of your class on each iteration through the loop and assign this new instance to `productPart`.

```
productPart = ...something here...
```

Comment: @Fraz: No. That's still not a *new* instance. You're still just reusing the same instance.